# How to show complete string when user select a date option in combobox

Tags: javascript, php

i have string like this.i retrive the string from url and explode string | and ~.and store in different variable. in String when i explode from | we find one,two,three...etc row ,of string.in a row of string second last value is date that i store in $item[6];and show throug for loop in a select box but now i want when user select a date in combobox show complete row with date.means if user select 2014-03-10 display complete row means

```
   33~WRIA/16458/2007~72~RAJESH MISHRA~UNION OF INDIA THROUGH ITS SECRETARY, AND 4 
   OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:19:41 07/03/2014
```

how can i do this.

```
33~WRIA/16458/2007~72~RAJESH MISHRA~UNION OF INDIA THROUGH ITS SECRETARY, AND 4 
OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:19:41 07/03/2014|33~WRIA/29576/2007~73~SMT. MEENA YADAV AND 
OTHERS~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:19:41
07/03/2014|9~COPP/43/2012~19~DASAPRAKASH HOTELS AND RESORTS PVT. LTD.~M/S KUMAR ASHIYANA
PVT. LTD.~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|9~COPP/43/2012~19~DASAPRAKASH HOTELS AND 
RESORTS PVT. LTD.~M/S KUMAR ASHIYANA PVT. LTD.~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55
07/03/2014|10~WRIA/50923/2012~27~LALLAN KUMAR~COAL INDIA LTD. THRU. ITS CHAIRMAN AND
 OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|10~WRIA/52176/2011~41~MANEESH THAKUR~STATE OF
 U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|10~WRIA/50923/2012~27~LALLAN UMAR~COAL 
 INDIA LTD. THRU. ITS CHAIRMAN AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 
 07/03/2014|10~WRIA/52176/2011~41~MANEESH THAKUR~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-
 06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|33~WRIA/30565/2005~31~VIJAY PRATAP SINGH~M/S TRIVENI STRUCTURALS
 LIMITED AND ANOTHER~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|33~WRIA/30565/2005~31~VIJAY PRATAP
 SINGH~M/S TRIVENI STRUCTURALS LIMITED AND ANOTHER~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 
 07/03/2014|39~WRIC/48169/2002~2~TAUFIQ KAMAL~STATE OF U.P. THRU  SECY. HOUSING GOVT. OF 
 U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|
```

Comment: please provide us what have you tried ?

Comment: sir i want display complete row after explode by |.means when i explode string from | i found many rows with strings.so after it in one row string having a date like 2014-03-10 and 2014-03-06 so when user select a date display string which are with date.

Comment: Will there be duplicates (i.e. the date appears more than once)?

Comment: ~.~ First you need to store each of the `$item` into one big array. Then find where the date matches and display rest of the elements. Also, make use associative keys instead of index (`$item['date']`)

Comment: alfred sir i sort date using unique_array() method.show i have only two distinct date.

Comment: but i want when user select a date display all string in row which are match with date

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$str = "copy your big string here";

$samp =explode("|",$str);

foreach($samp as $value)
{
echo "<textarea name='datestr[]' maxlength='1000' style='display:none'>$value</textarea>";
}

?>

<select id="dates">
<option>2014-03-10</option>
<option>2014-03-06</option>
</select>

<script>

$("#dates").change(function(e){

$.each($('[name^=datestr]'), function (i, item) {

var str = $(this).val();
if(str.indexOf($("#dates").val()) != -1)
  alert(str);

});

});

</script>
```

also add this line to `<head>` of html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```